# Finding extrema of a tri-variable function under a constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

We need to find extremum of $$f(x,y,z) = yz$$ under the constraint $$g(x,y,z) = 2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 - 12xy + 14xz - 35$$

Using the technique of Lagrange Multipliers, leads to four simultaneous equations which are quite tedious to solve esp. in an exam-setup under limited duration of time.

Entirely alternate solutions *and/or* techniques that efficiently solves the above system of equations are welcome.

Comment: So it is $f(x, y, \color{red}{z})$? or what is $z$?

Comment: My fault; apologies:( Editing in a moment.

Comment: Unless you have more constraints, it looks like you will have to go through the tedious way. e.g. Are you looking for a maximum? or just an extremum in general?

Comment: Is the constraint $g(x,y,z)=0$, then?

Comment: @amd Obviously :-)

Comment: @caverac The question asked for maximas and minimas. And, if we are solving it by LM, any way to make the process more efficient? It's damn boring and lengthy and I don't have a clue as to solving it in under 8-10 minutes (approx time per sum).

Comment: I cannot see any other, more straightforward, way. That's why I asked you if the problem gives you further constraints, because usually that reduces the number of options you need to look for. As I see it, you'd need to go through the long way. Sorry